# What additional line type can I use in R?

Tags: r

I need to represent four lines in R plots. I tried using solid, dotted and twodash. I need to figure out one more line type  that is distinct than other three?

Comment: Type `?par` and search for the section on `lty` for a list of options.

Answer (score 1):

The `type=` option in `plot` offers several options. You can find these options by running `?plot`. You'll see 'p' for points, 'l' for lines and so forth